# Is ELPA broken?

Tags: package-repositories, http

Emacs 26.1 as packaged in Debian buster.

After doing `M-x package-list-packages` I can select any package from the MELPA repo https://melpa.org/packages/ and then install it. But when I try to get any package from  the GNU ELPA repo https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ I get an error:

```
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
package-install-from-archive: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ack-1.8.tar: Bad Request
```

And of course I get the same error if I try to install it directly, outside the package menu with `M-x package-install <RET>  ack`.

When I browse `elpa.gnu.org` with Firefox I can download the file just fine, and I can also download it directly from the command line with

```
curl -L -O https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/ack-1.8.tar
```

What gives?

Update: I found https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=942413 . But I checked and I already have the latest signing key in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg` , namely `066DAFCB81E42C40`. So my problem must be different.

Comment: So now I know this has nothing to do with the signatures, it is definitely a TLS level problem. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=960311

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be this bug: https://debbugs.gnu.org/34341. 
It's fixed in Emacs 26.3+ and the workaround is:

`(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")`

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cdei4p/failed_to_download_gnu_archive_bad_request/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow I don't want to mess with TLS protocol settings, though :-(  I reported this to Debian,  if it turns out you were right I'll ACK.